# WCF server side async invocation

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I'm trying to implement the async operation on the server side using `Begin` and `End` operations on the server side. And for the operation `[OperationContract(AsyncPattern=true)]` is configured.

I have not generated the proxy on the client application but using the channel factory to create the service.
Though it looks like service instance is created. The actual operations on the server side are not being invoked.

Can somebody suggest what are the steps required to perform asynchronous operation on the server side.

If required I will share my entire sample project. Please let me know in case of any queries.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need is explained in the [MSDN-Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx)

I think the sample(code) there is rather good and just don't know what more to say here ;)
BTW: make sure to use the example from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Implement-a-WCF-2090bec8) as mentioned in the comments on the MSDN docs - but AFAIK the descriptions are fine